# How do you go back to a specific line in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Math Calculator Application. However I am wondering if there is a statement that allows you to go back to a certain line?

Let me clarify:

I am not referring to a loop. Here's a possibly scenerio: Let's say that the user has run the program and reached let's say line 54. If I have an if-else statement there, if there a way that I could make it so that "if (input = 0){go back to line 23}

Is there anything that may allow me to do this, not including a loop?

Comment: We are dealing with OOP here. Just make a method and call it

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't do it, it's bad design and difficult to follow.  Instead focus on how you might be able to re-use the functionality you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Oh my `$deity`, **absolutely not**. Constructs like that have been abolished since the BASICs of decades past, because they lead to completely unreadable, unmaintainable code.

Comment: If you ever add a new line before line 23, then your whole logic is gonna screw up, because of the offset

Comment: Isn't what you are asking for a goto  statement? They are generally considered a bad practise. And anyway java doesn't have goto statements. Though it has labeled breaks which can do the same thing but for a different reason. Check it out but i don't think that's what you need. What you are asking for implies that you need to restructure your code into smaller functions and conditions.

Comment: theoretically that's exactly what all programming do. but you must know how to do it in a correct way

Comment: Reinforcing what the other comments are saying:  Goto statements are part of the [Spaghetti Code Antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) and have been deprecated for a long time.  Don't do this.  Restructure your code so you can use one of the suggestions in the answers below.

Comment: Sounds like a loop to me.  Put `do {` on line 23, and `} while(condition);` on line 54, so that when the condition is true, you go back to line 23.

Comment: Man, just use a loop. It's what they're for.

Comment: Use a do-while loop. GOTO is not a good option and is not supported in Java. Java is a OOP language, don't try to use sequential programming options.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png

Answer (score 4):

Java does not have a goto (goto is a reserved word but not used).  Consider how your approach and language choice fit together.  There is likely a better way to do this.  Consider extracting a method or using a flag inside of a loop.  Without more information, guidance will be limited.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

The `goto` statement exists in C and C++, which Java is vaguely similar to, but it's generally considered *very* bad practice to use. It makes code difficult to read and debug. Here are some correct ways to solve this problem with more structured programming:

```
do {
    ...
} while (input == 0);
```

```
private void doTheThing() { // please use a better name!
    ...
    if (input == 0) doTheThing(); // recursion not recommended; see alternate
                                  // method below
}

// alternate method:
do {
    doTheThing();
} while (input == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use a loop?

Put your code in a function, then put in a loop that runs while input = 0.